# PHP - used memory varies greatly

Tags: php, memory

I have very big array serialized, compressed and stored in file.

A script is used to unpack:

```
$a = file_get_contents($file);
$a = base64_decode($a);
$a = gzuncompress($a);
$a = unserialize($a);
```

The problem is that after `gzuncompress($a)` memory_get_usage() always return 360 Mb,
but after `unserilize($a)` memory_get_usage() sometimes returns 1400 MB and sometimes 2800 MB, the difference is about 2 times.

What could be the reason for this difference?

Comment: A complex object takes up more memory than a serialized version of that object. The multiplier seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Evert That was not the OPs question, at least not as I understood the question. The OP observes that the memory usage is completely different between different executions of above code.

Comment: I wonder how you actually measure the memory usage?

Comment: @Evert The contents of the variables `$file` and `$a` are always the same each time the script runs, but memory consumption sometimes is 1400 Mb and sometimes is 2800 Mb

Comment: I see, misunderstood! Sounds garbage collection related then but now I'd just be guessing =)

Comment: @arkascha `memory_get_usage(true)/1048576`

Comment: The boolean parameter is documented as "Set this to true to get total memory allocated from system, including unused pages. ". Not sure why the gap is that wide, but certainly it is not meant to be deterministic.

Comment: Not related to your problem in anyway, but base64 encoding adds ~33% to the file size, and I'm curious why there's a need for that when writing to a binary file?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks! Forgot to remove base64_decode when changed the way of packing array into a file))